# Understanding this console error - 'top' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

so I've been working through this functionality to hide/show my menu on scroll with anchor linking.

It seems to be working as intended, however I'm getting an annoying console error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

Any suggestions please, what am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = !1,
        b = $(".menu-wrapper"),
        c = $(".menu a"),
        d = $(".intro-wrapper");
    b.hide(), $("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function () {
        var a = $(this.hash);
        return ($(this).addClass("active"), $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: a.offset().top
        }, 1e3), !1);
    }),

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var g = $(this).scrollTop(),
            h = $(this).height(),
            i = d.height();
        g >= i && !a ? (a = !0, b.stop().fadeIn()) : i > g && a && (a = !1, b.stop().fadeOut()), c.each(function () {
            var a = $(this.hash),
                b = a.offset().top,
                c = b + a.outerHeight();
            g + 1 > b && c > g + 1 ? $(this).addClass("active") : $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `a.offset().top` is available in all circumstances?  I would place some console.log code around each one to be sure; generally I find that it's unavailable due to how a is declared/defined.

Comment: `a.offset()` is `undefined` somewhere. Step through your code to find it.

Comment: Sounds like a.offset().top is not a valid property. Have you tried stepping into the code with chrome development tools yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this line:

```
var a = $(this.hash);
```

...can result in a jQuery set with nothing in it (e.g., `this.hash` doesn't identify any elements on the page). When you call `offset` on an empty jQuery set, it returns `undefined` (as do most other jQuery "getter" functions).

So either:

1. Identify why the element you're expecting `$(this.hash)` doesn't exist and fix that, or
2. Put a guard on the code that doesn't try to use `offset` when `a` is an empty jQuery set, e.g.:

   ```
   var a = $(this.hash);
   if (a[0]) {
       $(this).addClass("active");
       $("html, body").stop().animate({
           scrollTop: a.offset().top
       }, 1e3);
   }
   return false;
   ```

   or if you really want to minify/obfuscate it as with the previous code:

   ```
   var a = $(this.hash);
   return (a[0] && ($(this).addClass("active"), $("html, body").stop().animate({
       scrollTop: a.offset().top
   }, 1e3)), !1);
   ```

Comment: ah I figured it out, it wasn't related to the js, I missed the id for a section that the menu anchor was pointing to. var a = $(this.hash); this was expecting an additional element, and hence the .top was coming back undefined lol